# Trying to compile a qt project, getting input/output error in various places

Tags: c++, qt4, gnu

I am attempting to compile a qt project using the following sequence of commands

```
  > qmake -project
  > qmake
  > make
```

In the make process I keep getting the following error popping up.

```
{standard input}: Assembler messages:
{standard input}:21385: Fatal error: can't close Transfer.o: Input/output error make: *** [Transfer.o] Error 1
```

The same error is coming up for multiple classes, Originally I thought it was qt related because it first appeared in when the compiler tried to make a `moc` file. But now it seems to be popping up in other classes in my project.

I don't really know where to look for problems because I don't understand the error, Could anybody point me in the right direction? I'm happy to post code as needed.

Comment: Is your hard disk full? Are there strange permissions set on the folder you are trying to compile in? Does a file system check find errors?

Comment: Are you running on Windows or linux?  Use `df` command on Linux to check disk free space, and just `dir` on windows (last line is space free in bytes).

Comment: You where right sth! I didn't have enough disk space. The error kept getting produced in different parts of compiling depending on whether I had emptied my trash or not. haha, that was really confusing.

Comment: Thank you for posting this! Thanks @sth.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to some part of the code that assembler is not able to decode it.